# Keep container fixed and show horizontal scrollbar upon window resize

Tags: html, css

I have two elements inside my `<div>` container: Canvas and Table. I want these elements to have fixed position, and a horizontal scrollbar should display when window size is below the container's width.

When I try to resize the window, the table moves to the next line. Below is the link for my sample code. The two elements should remain side-by-side.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6mcbkt7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply width for the parent of the canvas and table. Here I tried applying width of 958px for '.tableAreaWrapperSub' and it works fine.
the width applying should be the sum of the widths of canvas and table plus margins/paddings or borders if any.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS-

```
.tableAreaWrapperSub {
    min-width: 1000px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The immediate parent container has to be set to overflow-x scroll. and also it has to be given a minimum width so that if the browser width is less than this, it will show a scroll bar.

Updated fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/pf2g4158/3/

Answer (score 1):

Add a min-width on the immediate container of the canvas and table.

It shouldn't matter but change container of the table to display:block instead of display:inline-block. Also add a float: left.

Append a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of the container containing the floated elements to make sure the container get the correct height, otherwise you end up with a 0px height on the container.

Modified your example: http://jsfiddle.net/pf2g4158/

```
<div class="tableAreaWrapperSub" style="min-width: 960px;">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400" style="float:left; border:1px solid black; background: #cdcdcd"></canvas>
  <div style="height:400px; display:block; float: left;">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```